# Why doesn't mapping over `parseInt` point-free style work as expected?

Tags: javascript, pointfree

I'm running the following in the Node.JS console:

```
> ["30", "31", "32"].map(x => parseInt(x))
[ 30, 31, 32 ]
> ["30", "31", "32"].map(parseInt)
[ 30, NaN, NaN ]
```

Why aren't these expressions identical? Is there a semantic difference in calling a function in point-free style as opposed to an anynomous function?

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with the second argument of `parseInt` being the number format.  I'm assuming that's it.  `parseInt("30", 0)` works fine.  `parseInt("31", 1)` does not

Comment: I think, it's most probably the culprit (as always with `parseInt`). But why does it receive a second argument at all? There are three inputs and three outputs, shouldn't there be only one argument per execution? `"31"` doesn't look like octal either.

Comment: `map` passes in more than just the element to the callback.  It will also pass in the index.  That's what the `0` and `1` are in my first comment.

Comment: Ah, I think you are onto something -- `map` has `index` as its second argument, that will probably be it. Want to add the answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
["30", "31", "32"].map(function(){
  console.log(arguments);
});
```

The issue is most likely related to map passing more than just the element to the callback.  It passes the element, index, and the whole array.  So if you are letting the map pass all that into the `parseInt` method, the index is most likely causing issues with the method knowing how to convert the string to a number of the related base.

Answer (score 2):

`parseInt` accepts two arguments: the numeric string and the base. `Array#map` provides the element and the index as the first two arguments to its callback, which makes some of the numbers unparseable (the main cause likely being that there are digits that are invalid for the specified base, such as having the digit 2 when parsing a string as binary), resulting in NaN. The Number function can be used instead to avoid this pitfall, as it ignores all arguments except the first.

```
["30", "31", "32"].map(Number)
```

Comment: Thanks for additional note about using `Number`!

Comment: @NikolaiProkoschenko Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

The function you pass to `map` actually gets three parameters from `map`: the element, the index, and the whole list.

In your first example you are explicitly binding `x` and passing it to `parseInt`, which takes two arguments, the string and a format. If you leave format null, it defaults to base 10.

In your second example, you are sending the arguments sent by `map` directly to `parseInt`, which is telling `parseInt` to use the index as a second argument.

```
> ["30", "31", "32"].map(console.log)
30 0 [ '30', '31', '32' ]
31 1 [ '30', '31', '32' ]
32 2 [ '30', '31', '32' ]
```